# fundamental group of the complement of an effective divisor in a non projective complex manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, fundamental-groups

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold, non necessairly projective (in my case of interset, it has no nonconstant meromorphic functions). Let $D$ be an effective divisor.

I couldn't find results on the (non) abelianity of $\pi_1(M\setminus D)$ in this context. I've seen that when $M$ is projective and $D$ is ample, then it is true, but i didn't understood well the proof.

Are there results linked with the normal bundle of $D$, or if we know something about the line bundle $L$ such that $D=(s)_0$ for $s\in H^0(M,L)$ ? Precisely, if $M$ is a compact and simply connected complex manifold, and $D =(s)_0$ where $s\in H^0(M,L)$ for some line bundle $L$ on $M$, can we say something about the abelianity of $\pi_1(M\setminus D,x)$ ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: What if $M = \mathbb {CP}^1$ and $D = \{pt\}$ (ignoring the condition on the meromorphic functions)?

Comment: Then $M\setminus D$ is simply connected. But i don't see how i can relate it to the previous context ?  If there are two independants sections of $O_M(D)$ then we can form a meromorphic function such that $D$ is the zero, but $M$ has no meromorphic non constant function in my case. I'm missing something sorry, may be in the smooth category ?

Comment: In your second paragraph, do you mean that if $M$ is projective and $D$ is ample, then $\pi_1(M\setminus D)$ is non-abelian?

Comment: No sorry i was unclear. I only suppose that $D$ is the zero locus of a global section $s\in H^0(M,L)$ for some line bundle.

Comment: Out of interest, where is the claim about ample divisors written?